# Spring mail MimeMessage has an incorrect "From " set

Tags: spring, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am using spring mail to send an email via google's smptp server. I am setting my email templates "From" header but for some reason when I do receive the mail as a sender I get the owner of the smtp account. (which happens to be me again).

```
MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
helper.setText(forgottenPassowrdMailTemplate.getText()
                   .replace("%firstName%", token.getUser().getFirstName())
                   .replace("%lastName%", token.getUser().getLastName())
                   .replace("%link%", url + token.getToken()), true);
        helper.setTo(token.getUser().getEmail());
        helper.setFrom(forgottenPassowrdMailTemplate.getFrom());
        helper.setSubject(forgottenPassowrdMailTemplate.getSubject());
```

am I forgetting something ? I a am explicitly setting the "From" header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a `from` address that is different from the account's address. There are security measures by Google to avoid abuse, which could be fatal if you could just send with any arbitrary `from` address via Google's SMTP server. You need to link and verify your other account with the account you want to send the mail with. See [here](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370). Your original email address will still be available in the headers and visible to the receipient.

But why don't you just use the other accounts credentials (and mail server, if it is not a Google account)?

Comment: First Thanks for the answer, that explains my problems. What do you mean other account? I am testing using my google account to connect to the smtp server, but the actual emails are still send to me. It's a password recovery mechanism  and I am the user requesting the password change so it appears as if I am sending email to me :)

Comment: From Google's perspective, any address which is not the sender address is a forgery. Unless you use authentication, they will prevent it.

Comment: @pmanolov You just can't use arbitrary `from` addresses, only the ones linked to your account and even then the mails are sent as `from:support@example.com on behalf of fred@googlemaildomainname.mock`. With "other account" I meant the account of the email address you want to set (`forgottenPassowrdMailTemplate.getFrom()`). You need to have control over that one. "Raw" SMTP does not check what you enter in the from header; Google does. SMTP servers that don't check anything are likely to be blacklisted as spam servers very fast.

Comment: That's all right I use google's smtp only for testing purpose. The actual prod smtp is different, plus emails are going to be distributed within a closed network. I just thought that I screwed something. Thanks again for the clarification!