# Spring/Java Mail: The FROM address is being ignored

Tags: java, spring, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail with Spring FW. Everything is working nicely, but I don't know why the FROM address is always wrong; it seems to ignore it and say where it's really from instead. What I want will become clearer in a moment. First, here's my code:

**CONFIG**

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="25"/>
    <property name="username" value="[my gmail address]"/>
    <property name="password" value="[my password]"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <!--<prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>-->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**HELPER CLASS**

```
@Service("mailService")
public class MailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;

    public void sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String body) {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
            helper.setFrom(from);
            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText(body, true);
            mailSender.send(message);
        }
        catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MailService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    //etc...
}
```

**CONTROLLER CODE SNIPPET**

```
mailService.sendMail(
    contactModel.getEmail(), //From
    Constants.DefaultEmailAddress, //To
    "Enquiry from site", "Phone: " + contactModel.getPhone() + "<br />Message: <br />" + contactModel.getMessage());
```

Basically, `contactModel` is a normal Java class with a few properties for collecting info from a user on the **contact us** form. When I send the e-mail, I am currently seeing the FROM address the same as the TO address. What I can't figure out is whether I need to make some change in the config or if maybe Gmail is perhaps not allowing me to do this. Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Spring mail MimeMessage has an incorrect “From ” set](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9140611/1350869)

Comment: Thanks, Frank.. that's it then... Google screwed me on this one. If you add that as an answer, then I will accept it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring mail MimeMessage has an incorrect "From " set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140176/spring-mail-mimemessage-has-an-incorrect-from-set)

Answer (score 8):

Google won't allow you to send mail from your account saying you are somebody you're not (other domain).

So it will overwrite Sender with account you authorized with saving what you've specified in `X-google-original-from` header. You have to add your external account as specified in https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en (or add your external domain to be managed in Google if you have Google Apps).

Answer (score 8):

To use gmail account with changed "setFrom" to another email address you have to do:

1. Add new address to your gmail account. Instruction is here: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en
2. Set "Always send from a different address". Instruction is under the same link.
3. In gmail account Settings/Accounts and Import/Send mail as set your new email address as default.
4. In AppConfig.java type:

   ```
   @Bean
   public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
   JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
   mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
   mailSender.setPort(587);
   mailSender.setUsername("address@gmail.com");
   mailSender.setPassword(your gmail's password);
   mailSender.getJavaMailProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   mailSender.getJavaMailProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
   return mailSender;
   ```

   }
5. In EmailServiceImplementation.java type this:

   ```
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
   import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

   @Service       
   public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {
   @Autowired
   private JavaMailSender mailSender;
   @Override
   public void sendEmail(String fromAddress, String toAddress, String subject, String body) {
   SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

   mailMessage.setTo(toAddress);
   mailMessage.setFrom("emailWhichYouWishToShow@gmail.com");
   mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
   mailMessage.setText(body);

   mailSender.send(mailMessage);
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your to address is not being set, I would put a logging statement to see what is being passed to the sendMail method.

In your class you should be using MailSender not MailSenderImpl as the MailSender is the interface you want to be using. In my application I use SimpleMailMessage instead of MimeMessage and that works for me, below is code snippet I have used in the past.

```
@Autowired
private MailSender mailSender;

// Email is my own Pojo with from, to, subject and body properties.
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void sendEmail(Email email)
    {
            // create email message
            SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();
            msg.setFrom(email.getFromAddress());
            msg.setTo(email.getToAddress());
            msg.setSubject(email.getSubject());
            msg.setText(email.getBody());

            // send the message using spring mail sender
            this.mailSender.send(msg);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use the JavaMailSenderImpl because when I tried using MailSender only, then I could not use HTML. Also, I have debugged the code and I can see the correct address is being sent to the sendEmail() method and set on the MimeMessage object.

Comment: @Matt Then use the JavaMailSender interface instead of the implementation.

Comment: Frank, that's fair enough, thanks.. but it doesn't solve my problem... can someone please tell me how to do what I want to do here?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but consider following instructions from Google

> You can connect to the Google Apps mail servers using SMTP or SSL. If you connect using SMTP, you can only send mail to Gmail or Google Apps users; if you connect using SSL, you can send mail to anyone.
>   If your device or application supports SSL, connect to smtp.gmail.com on port 465 or 587.

and you are using port 25.